Image.network() "Failed to decode image" when displaying the image obtained from the odoo 17 api
I tried to get an image via the odoo 17 API, when I checked using Postman the image was successfully obtained but when I tried to display it it didn't work.
this is my code
ClipOval(
  child: Image.network(
    employee.image!,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    headers: 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',,
    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
       const ClipOval(
           child: Icon(Icons.person),
       ),
  ),
)

this log from debug console
E/FlutterJNI( 4601): Failed to decode image
E/FlutterJNI( 4601): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.


Are you on flutter web?

also, does the errorBuilder correctly fire?

flutter for mobile android, and errorBuilder is displayed

Can you try opening the URL in your regular browser?
also, please share the URL If you can

if i open the image url in browser is unauthenticated because must have access token for access the image. sorry, i cant share the URL

I think youre running this on an emulator

yes, i use emulator because i create for android application
